# how to insert one value to different rows

Tags: php, mysql, insert

i wanted the code to insert the same value to different rows that are checked in the list(the list is queried from the database.) but it says
"Notice: Array to string conversion in \enrol.php on line 5",

here is my section.php

```
    <table border=1px>
    <th>SELECT</th>
    <th>ID NUMBER</th>
    <th>NAME</th>
    <th>COURSE</th>
    <th>YEAR</th>

    <?php session_start();
    include('connect.php');
    $group=$_REQUEST['idEdit'];
    echo $group;

    $sql="SELECT * FROM login WHERE section IS NULL or section = 0";
    $result=mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error() );


        while($arr=mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {
            echo '<tr><td><form action="enrol.php" method="post"><input type="checkbox" name="idnumber[]" value="'.$arr['idnumber'].'"></td>'.
                 '<td>'.$arr['idnumber'].",&nbsp</td>".
                 '<td>'.$arr['lastname'].",".$arr['firstname']."&nbsp</td>".
                 '<td>'.$arr['course']."&nbsp</td>".
                 '<td>'.$arr['year']."&nbsp</td></tr>";}

         $idnumber=$arr['idnumber'];
         ?> 

        <input type="hidden" value="<?php $group ?>" name="group">
        <input type="submit" value="Enrol Student" name="submit">
        </form>
    </table>
```

and here is my enrol.php

```
    <?php 
    if(isset($_REQUEST['submit'])){

    $ids = join (', ', $_POST['idnumber']);
    $sql="INSERT INTO login (section) values ('$_POST[group]') WHERE idnumber='$ids'";
    mysql_query($sql);

    $count=mysql_affected_rows();

    if($count==1){
                  echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Added Sucessfully")</script>';

    }else{
                echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Error!")</script>';

                }
     }
    ?>
```

how can i solve this problem? i have been trying to search for a solution but i cant seem to find any. please help.

Comment: Try implode function instead of join.

Comment: you can not `insert` to one `table` using `where` clause...use `update`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use implode instand of join

```
$ids = implode(', ', $_POST['idnumber']);
```

Comment: thanks @thumber nirimal, i tried your suggestion and it did not produce any error but still wasn't able to insert into the database

Comment: first ry to print query like this                                         $sql="INSERT INTO login (section) values ('$_POST[group]') WHERE idnumber='$ids'";                                                      echo $sql;  .....and check there is any problem in query

Comment: it printed out INSERT INTO login (section) values ('AnaPhy101') WHERE idnumber='50715, 17583'

Comment: basically, i want the same value to be inserted into those different idnumbers how can i do that?

Comment: try this query......                                                      $sql="update login set section='".$_POST[group]."' WHERE idnumber IN ($ids)";

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27475/discussion-between-thumber-nirmal-and-roseanne)

Answer (score 1):

I think,You are getting the value of the hidden field group null.
First of all You echo group value in the hidden Field.

```
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $group; ?>" name="group">
```

I hope your problem will be Solved.
You got my point?

Comment: even if i placed the echo, it still wasn't inserted into the database

Comment: you get the value of this hidden field? or not? print value of group and idnumber in that page. then say me.I think you didnot get the idnumber value.Plz check it.

Comment: it did get the value it, because when i printed the sql in the enrol.php i got this INSERT INTO login (section) values ('AnaPhy101') WHERE idnumber='50715, 17583'.

Answer (score 0):

Use [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)

```
 <?php 
        if(isset($_REQUEST['submit'])){

        $ids = implode(', ', $_POST['idnumber']);
        $sql="INSERT INTO login (section) values ('$_POST[group]') WHERE idnumber='$ids'";
        mysql_query($sql);

        $count=mysql_affected_rows();

        if($count==1){
                      echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Added Sucessfully")</script>';

        }else{
                    echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Error!")</script>';

                    }
         }
        ?>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but it still didn't insert into the database

Answer (score 0):

There is some quote issue when you are fetching post values. Try it.

```
$sql="INSERT INTO login (section) values ('".$_POST["group"]."') WHERE idnumber='".$ids."'";
```

Comment: You were asking for line 5 error that was the solution for that. You need to debug it by your self.

Comment: but the title of the question is "how to insert one value to different rows". i tried debugging it but i can't, that's why i posted a question

Comment: @roseanne,What is wrong with inserting record. Please post the error what you are getting from msyql or use. $query = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

Comment: i placed  
$sql="update login set section='".$_POST['group']."' WHERE idnumber IN ($ids)"; echo $sql; 
$query = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
it did not printed out any errors it only printed out
update login set section='AnaPhy101' WHERE idnumber IN (50715)

Answer (score 0):

i got the answer thanks to @thumber nirmal and all those who responded with this question. here is the working code for enrol.php

```
    <?php include('connect.php');
    if(isset($_REQUEST['submit'])){

    $ids = implode(', ', $_POST['idnumber']);
    $sql="update login set section='".$_POST['group']."' WHERE idnumber IN ($ids)"; 
    echo $sql; 
    $query = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_query($sql);

    $count=mysql_affected_rows();

    if($count==1){
                  echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Added Sucessfully")</script>';

    }else{
                echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Error!")</script>';

                }
     }
    ?>
```